# Storing Class objects to EEPROM or other memory

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

In dynamic memory I am able to create and operate perfectly on objects.
I create these objects by parsing an SD card which works perfect.
Due to the constraint of dynamic memory on a microcontroller I would like
to store these objects on EEPROM or FRAM.

The following functions (from FRAM library) can be used to store bytes from dynamic memory to FRAM:

```
  void     write8 (uint16_t addr, uint8_t value);
  void     write (uint16_t addr, const uint8_t *values, size_t count);
  uint8_t  read8  (uint16_t addr);
```

The Objects have the following class:

```
class Person
{
  public:
    char* m_pStrName;
    int m_nAge;
    bool m_fIsMale;

    //Constructor
    Person(char* strName, int nAge, bool fIsMale);
    Person();

    //Copy constructor
    Person( const Person &obj );

    //Destructor
    ~Person();
};
```

I tried the following to create a Person object and store it:

```
Person* pTestPerson = new Person();
fram.write(0x0000, pTestPerson, sizeof(Person));
```

//Due to the little amount of dynamic memory (where I created this object)
//should I free and delete the pointer to the person?

```
delete pTestPerson;
pTestPerson = nullptr;
```

//Now the fun part, how to read a sizeof(Person) amount of bytes and create a new valid Person object? I tried the following, but probably is nonsense:

```
Person* pReadPerson = new Person();

for (int x = 0; x < sizeof(Person); x++)
{
    *(pReadPerson + x) = fram.read(0x0000 + x);
}
```

Comment: This will store the pointer `char* m_pStrName;` but not the name. It is the same problem as writing structs to binary files multiple discussed here. Have a look at [Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). The trivial (all contained) case e.g. is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384309), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542617), ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to write custom serialization/deserialization code for your object. It is a very common problem in computer programming in general, so that a lot of languages have serialization built in (Python is one prominent example).

In your case you could do something like this:

1. Write m_pStrName lentgh
2. Write m_nAge
3. Write m_fIsMale
4. Write contents of m_pStrName

Deserialization would look similar:
 1. Read m_pStrName and store it somethere aside
 2. Read m_nAge and store it in your object
 3. Read m_fIsMale and store it in your object
 4. Allocate "length of m_pStrName" bytes and attach it to m_pStrName pointer
 5. Read name and store it in m_pStrName memory block (watch out for string length)

Data serialization and deserialization is tricky, because it is very easy to make a tiny little mistake that breaks your object completely.

Another serious problem is data versioning. If you update your `Person` layout, you need to change your serialization code and (possibly) make it backward-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The objects of a type of a class don't store some attributes like methods, vptr in the memory allocated to the object. Thus you cannot store classes over there in the direct meaning of this word. However, You could put the data payload only to the ROM and the class could operate with a reference to it. So, in another words, the class will implement only functionality working with the content of the ROM according to your needs. Then the RAM memory occupation will be minimized.